# A Replace Function in Lisp That Duplicates Mathematica Functionality

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, lisp, wolfram-mathematica

What is the easiest way to accomplish the following in a Mathematica clone or in any version of Lisp(any language is probably okay actually even Haskell)?  It doesn't appear any lisps [have a similar replace function](http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp).

```
Replace[{
  f[{x, "[", y, "]"}],
  f@f[{x, "[", y, y2, "]"}]
  }
 , f[{x_, "[", y__, "]"}] :> x[y],
 Infinity]
```

and a return value of  `{x[y], f[x[y, y2]]}`

It replaces all instances of `f[{x_, "[", y__, "]"}]` in args where `x_` represents a single variable and `y__` represents one or more variables.

In lisp the function and replacement would probably be the equivalent(forgive me I am not the best with Lisp).  I'm looking for a function of the form `(replace list search replace)`.

```
(replace
  '(
   (f (x "[" y "]"))
   (f (f '(x "[" y y2 "]")))
  )
  '(f (x_ "[" y__ "]"))
  '(x y)
)
```

and get a return value of `((x y) (f (x y y2)))`.

Comment: This *is* stackoverflow.

Comment: @ScottHunter Fixed here is the link to Mathematica.se post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94720/duplicate-mathematica-functionality-in-mathematica-clone-or-lisp

Comment: Mind telling us what that Mathematica code *does*?  And what you've tried that didn't work?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want [**subst-if**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It replaces all instances of `f[{x_, "[", y__, "]"}]` where x_ represents a single variable and y__ represents one or more variables.

Comment: @William OK, but `f[{x_, "[", y__, "]"}]` isn't a Lisp object.  What would the lisp counterpart be?  Something like "every list of the form `(f x (y...))` is replaced by `(x y...)`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think `(f (x_ "[" y__ "]"))` is the closest you can get without knowing the proper syntax for doing multiple or single replacements.

Comment: so actual "[" and "]" strings in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89751/discussion-between-william-and-joshua-taylor).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes.  Give me a couple minutes and I'll post a self contained example.

Comment: **and get a return value of `((x y), (f (x y y2)))`.**   What does the comma represent in that return value?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ignore the comma

Comment: @Bill Sed just includes regex parsing(from my knowledge).  If anything does this it will probably a lisp or maybe some variant of Haskell or something.

Comment: @Bill http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp#lisp-macros  It doesn't look that is natively supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's give it another try.

First, install  [`quicklisp`](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) and use it to fetch, install and load [`optima`](https://github.com/m2ym/optima) and [`alexandria`](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html).

```lisp
(ql:quickload :optima)
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
(use-package :alexandria)
```

The functions from `alexandria` referenced below are `ensure-list` and `last-elt`. If you don't have them installed, you can use the following definitions:

```lisp
(defun ensure-list (list) (if (listp list) list (list list)))
(defun last-elt (list) (car (last list)))
```

We define rules as functions from one form to another.
Below, the function tries to destructure the input as `(f (<X> "[" <ARGS> "]")`, where `<ARGS>` is zero or more form. If destructuring fails, we return `NIL` (we expect non-matching filters to return `NIL` hereafter).

```lisp
(defun match-ugly-funcall (form)
  (optima:match form
    ((list 'f (cons x args))
     (unless (and (string= "[" (first args))
                  (string= "]" (last-elt args)))
       (optima:fail))
     `(,x ,@(cdr (butlast args))))))

(match-ugly-funcall '(f (g "[" 1 3 5 4 8 "]")))
; => (G 1 3 5 4 8)
```

Then, we mimic Mathematica's Replace with this function, which takes a form and a list of rules to be tried. It is possible to pass a single rule (thanks to `ensure-list`). If a list of list of rules is given, a list of matches should be returned (to be done).

```lisp
(defun match-replace (form rules &optional (levelspec '(0)))
  (setf rules (ensure-list rules))
  (multiple-value-bind (match-levelspec-p recurse-levelspec-p)
      (optima:ematch levelspec
        ((list n1 n2) (if (some #'minusp (list  n1 n2))
                          (optima:fail)
                          (values (lambda (d) (<= n1 d n2))
                                  (lambda (d) (< d n2)))))
        ((list n) (if (minusp n)
                      (optima:fail)
                      (values (lambda (d) (= d n))
                              (lambda (d) (< d n)))))
        (:infinity (values (constantly t) (constantly t))))
    (labels
        ((do-replace (form depth)
           (let ((result
                   (and (funcall match-levelspec-p depth)
                        (some (lambda (r) (funcall r form)) rules))))
             (cond
               (result (values result t))
               ((and (listp form)
                     (funcall recurse-levelspec-p depth))
                (incf depth)
                (do (newlist
                     (e (pop form) (pop form)))
                    ((endp form) (values form nil))
                  (multiple-value-bind (result matchedp) (do-replace e depth)
                    (if matchedp
                        (return (values (nconc (nreverse newlist) 
                                               (list* result form)) t))
                        (push e newlist)))))
               (t (values form nil))))))
      (do-replace form 0))))
```

And a test:

```lisp
(match-replace '(a b (f (x "[" 1 2 3 "]")) c d)
               #'match-ugly-funcall
               :infinity)
; => (A B (X 1 2 3) C D)
;    T
```

In order to replace all expressions instead of the first matching one, use this instead:

```lisp
  (defun match-replace-all (form rules &optional (levelspec '(0)))
      (setf rules (ensure-list rules))
      (multiple-value-bind (match-levelspec-p recurse-levelspec-p)
          (optima:ematch levelspec
            ((list n1 n2) (if (some #'minusp (list  n1 n2))
                              (optima:fail)
                              (values (lambda (d) (<= n1 d n2))
                                      (lambda (d) (< d n2)))))
            ((list n) (if (minusp n)
                          (optima:fail)
                          (values (lambda (d) (= d n))
                                  (lambda (d) (< d n)))))
            (:infinity (values (constantly t) (constantly t))))
        (labels
            ((do-replace (form depth)
               (let ((result
                       (and (funcall match-levelspec-p depth)
                            (some (lambda (r) (funcall r form)) rules))))
                 (cond
                   (result result)
                   ((and (listp form)
                         (funcall recurse-levelspec-p depth))
                    (incf depth)
                    (mapcar (lambda (e) (do-replace e depth)) form))
                   (t form)))))
          (do-replace form 0))))
```

Comment: +1 but it appears at first glance that the function only works with replacements list at depth 1.  In addition I was hopeful to have something over the form `(replace list search rule)` similar to M.

Comment: @William Surely it should not be too difficult to modify the implementation to suit your need, but the at the moment I don't have much time and I am not sure to know exactly what you need. I never used Mathematica, and the reference I get when looking for Replace is this one: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html. I would gladly be shown another reference if you have one. It says that  "[Replace] does not map down to subparts", though there is an  optional *levelspec* argument. Also, I don't see anything similar to `(replace list search rule)`.

Comment: Technically it is `Replace[expr,rules,levelspec]` but because rules are two parts in would translate into something like `Replace[expr,rule1,rule2,levelspec]` so it would be `(replace expr rule1 rule2 levelspec)`.  `levelspec` because I believe your example only works for 1 level spec.

Comment: @William I made some changes. I hope this is sufficient for your need.

Comment: I'm going to let it automatically award you half the bounty because I appreciate the help but as it stands it doesn't work correctly all the time.  For example try running the following `(match-replace '(a b 
                    (f (x "[" 1 2 3 "]"))
                    (f (x "[" 1 2 3 "]"))
                c d)
               #'match-ugly-funcall
               :infinity)` it only replaces the first match and not both.  I'm still amazed lisp doesn't have such functionality more or less built in to the program.  `match-replace` looks quiet complex.

Comment: @William Oh... I thought Replace should quit as soon as one rule matched (vs. ReplaceAll; note the secondary return value which tells you if a match was found), so I tried very hard to stop as soon as possible (I don't have Mathematica to test things). Otherwise it would be simpler (mapcar). Lisp has subst-if, subst, which make sense for Lisp, but Mathematica is designed for other needs and you won't find exactly the same features without having to reimplement them. In particular, dealing with levelspec was verbose, but not difficult.

Comment: You can install [mathics](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/wiki/Installing) if you you don't have Mathematica it supports most of the basic commands.  I'll go ahead and give you the bounty if you don't mind fixing `match-replace` to replace all values.

Comment: @William Thanks for the link. I modified the answer.

Comment: It appears to work thanks!  Is there a way to use a lambda instead of creating another function?

Comment: I have another question what would happen if you had something like `f[a_,b_,c_,x_,y__,z___]` would that be to complex for your example?

Comment: @William Thanks. The case for rules as functions is to avoid limiting ourselves with what rules can match: you can rely on closures and generic functions too, if needed. Regarding your example, the one thing that is somewhat tricky is `y__` followed by `z__`, since there could be multiple ways to partition a list and bind the variables to different sublists. This can be done, but details matter. Depending on your needs, maybe Prolog is a better option. If you could narrow the scope of your question and tell us why you need this, you would certainly have more useful answers.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code and I'm getting `undefined-function: LAST-ELT`

Comment: @Willam You can replace `(last-elt args)` with `(first(last args))` because `last` returns the last cons-cell. `last-elt` is part of the alexandria library.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, how Mathematica manages to obfuscate everything by applying its renown NIH approach.

Basically, you're looking for a function to perform string replacement according to some pattern. In most languages, this is accomplished with regular expressions.

For instance, in Common Lisp using the [cl-ppcre](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) library it will look something like this:

```
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all
 ;; regular expression you match against with groups
 "f\\[{(x[^ ]*), \"\\[\", ((y[^ ]* ?)+), \"\\]\"}\\]"
 ;; your string
 "{f[{x, \"[\", y, \"]\"}], f@f[{x, \"[\", y, y2, \"]\"}]}"
 ;; substitution expression using groups 1 & 2 
 "\\1[\\2]")
```

Surely, you can write a specialized 20-line function for this problem of matching and substituting subtrees using `subst` and recursion, but if all that you want is cases similar to the presented one you can get away with a simple regex-based approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm looking for pattern matching not REGEX.

Comment: @William regex is pattern matching on strings. :)

Comment: You really shouldn't parse a gramar with REGEX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: is there a grammar behind this? where's its spec?

Comment: The wolfram language spec(at least the basics of the grammar) I believe are described [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216/Wolfram%20Programming%20Language%20Fundamentals.pdf)

Comment: I don't see a description of the `Replace` function there, however